# If Voltage has tolerance 110V-220V, Why Electricity Broke?

Tags: power-electronics

First, my knowledge is, if an electronics (computer) needs 220 Volt. And there is drop voltage when we use it (let say 200V). Current will go high, and the component will be hot. And it (component) will broken, right?

What will happen if there is tolerance voltage like an adapter smartphone/notebook that written 110-220Volt? Is it make broken or not?

If not broken, why electronics like computer, television not build for it (have voltage tolerance also)?

Comment: Although the wording isn't very clear, I assume what you're asking is why some devices are rated for 220V while some are rated for 110-220V and latter will be protected against a voltage drop from 220V to around 200V.

Comment: For appliances designed for universal voltages (100 to 270 volts), as you said current goes up when they are operated at lower voltage. But components run hotter at higher current not entirely true because average power remains the same. Even if some circuit runs at higher temperature, they will be equipped with thermal protection.

Comment: @soosaisteven "But components run hotter at higher current not entirely true because average power remains the same". Average power remains the same is correct. Since, P = VI, But what make component getting hot is current, right?

Comment: @chamod yes, I asked like you said.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They certainly COULD build computer and TV power supplies that way. They might be a bit more expensive to build and test.

And I guess manufacturers don't think that people take their TV's or desktop computers with them when they travel. So they prefer not to add any extra cost to them.

But people often travel to other countries with their mobile pones, laptops and cameras. So it is more important to support multiple voltages with portable devices.

For larger appliances, which have resistance heating elements or AC-powered electric motors, it is not so easy to support multiple voltages. It is not practical at all.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few countries in the world where both voltages are present within the country- and you can find dual voltage appliances for sale at relatively reasonable prices. **South Korea** is one.

The price is still going to be higher than single-voltage appliances- enough difference that for small appliances with big heaters or AC motors they will not be made with wide voltage range or dual voltage for the general market. There are often regulatory requirements that are region or country specific that go along with the voltage requirement and tend to segment the market.